# Is there a more elegant solution for filling a List from a Map?

Tags: java

I try to fill the List from the Map. In case the list is `NULL` I will create a new List and add a new created element otherwise add this element to existing list.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution in JAVA8 for this.
Any help appreciated.

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
List<MyObject> list = myMap.get("key");
myMap.put("key", list == null ? Arrays.asList(new MyObject()) : Arrays.asList(list, new MyObject()));
```

Comment: you can use PutIfAbsent method as well.

Comment: @notionquest PutIfAbsent eagerly creates the value (the ArrayList here) in every call whilst computetIfAbsent only when the key is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `Arrays.asList(list, new MyObject())` should instead add a new `MyObject` instance to `list`, then yes, you can use [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) to make the code more readable:

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.computeIfAbsent("key", key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new MyObject());
```

If `"key"` is not present as a key in the `Map`, then a mapping will be created to a new `ArrayList` instance (which is returned). Otherwise, the existing `List` will be returned by the call to `computeIfAbsent`, allowing you to add a new element to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply make sure your get doesn't return null in the first place:

```
List<MyObject> list = myMap.getOrDefault("key", new ArrayList<>);
```

Then you'll end up with

```
List<MyObject> list = myMap.getOrDefault("key", new ArrayList<>);
list.add(new MyObject());
myMap.put("key", list);
```

Comment: That is another solution which could be used, good answer though! Thanks!